# .Net Application stop working on windows 8

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, windows-8.1

I have a 32 bits VB.Net application that uses the Framework 4. The app run fine when installed on Windows 7. When I installed the application on Windows 8.1 in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallationFolder, it will stop working without giving any error. I've have catch the event MyApplication.UnhandledException to handle unexpected error and log the error.

When I check the log for the error, there is nothing. Next I check the Windows log and there is nothing about my application crashing.

Now the weirdest part, if I install the application in an other folder the program Files, like C:\Test\InstallFolder, the application work fine without crashing.

The application read an XML file and convert it to either an Access Database or SQL Server. The app validate the XML using XSD files that are under the installation folder. There is also an other XML file that is deserialize to be save in the database.

What could cause the application to stop working without any error?

Comment: sounds like it could be file/folder permissions related.  where is the db located and/or XML files location?

Comment: To expand on what Plutonix said, if you are not providing a path for the file, it is being written to the folder your EXE is in. Because of security reasons, you cannot write to the Program Files folder unless you have turned off UAC or run the application with elevated permissions. Try running your app as administrator and see if you get your error log.

Comment: Any clues to be found in EventViewer?

Comment: My crystal ball says that it is not *actually* a 32-bit app so it cannot open the .xsd files.  It will look in c:\program files instead of c:\program files (x86).  The file system redirector will not be active in C:\Test\InstallFolder

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your installation path in windows 8.1 it seems that your windows 8.1 machine is 64bit.

So I would like to suggest to try the following.

1. Check your project build settings for the target processor.
2. It must be an permission issue. Try to put your files (XML etc) into AppData folder and then access it, because applications do not have permission to write data under program files folder. So it may solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I am hopping this thread to get a quick answer. So if I developed my application using Windows 7, it won't be any issue to run the program in Windows 8.1?